# How to extract specific value from a string in logic app

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am creating a logic app to fetch infected file name containing malware from the notification email received from Microsoft 365 defender.

Fetching this parameter from (When a new email arrives ) trigger

[image]

Output of (Body Preview)

[image]

I want to get the file name ( After Incident Name shown within ' ' ) from the above output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to skin this cat but using standard expressions, try this ...

[image: Flow]

The sample flow above simply initialises your text and then the next step that sets the `Sub Text` variable contains this expression ...

```
split(variables('Text'), '''')[1]
```

This is the end result ...

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you please explain in the split expression why are we using double quotes and what is the use of [1] here ?

Comment: They’re actually single quotes escaped and the [1] is the second item in the array (arrays start from 0) which represents the text between the quotes. This solution only works as long as the structure of the text you provide stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with @Skin, I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

Firstly , taken a trigger `when a email arrives`
then initialized the body as Body Preview function of the trigger to a variable.

[image]

Then in compose I splited ,

```
split(string(variables('emo')), '''')[1]
```

[image]

Output:

[image]

**Code View:**

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose_2": {
                "inputs": "@split(string(variables('emo')), '''')[1]",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "emo",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": "@triggerBody()?['BodyPreview']"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_new_email_arrives": {
                "evaluatedRecurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Minute",
                    "interval": 3
                },
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['office365']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/Mail/OnNewEmail",
                    "queries": {
                        "folderPath": "Inbox",
                        "importance": "Normal"
                    }
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Minute",
                    "interval": 3
                },
                "splitOn": "@triggerBody()?['value']",
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "office365": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3-b83a074c23f/resourceGroups/jja/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365",
                    "connectionName": "office365",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/b83c1e\83a074c23f/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/office365"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```